# Database tables, hibernate

Tags: sql, oracle

I am building a web application which has quite a few maintenance screens.I have probably a pretty basic question but I still want to be clear.I have been provided a sketch of the database tables that are supposed to be present.The tables provided me do have a primary key field for example dept_id that may be sequentially generated.Instead what has been given to me is a DEPT_KEY(which is a varchar2) field.Can I just use the varchar2 fields as primary key fields or should I have a number field-DEPT_ID that is sequentially generated.Infact none of the fields provided has an ID field.They all have Keys.

Thanks

Comment: Anything that is sequentially generated reduces your effort.

Comment: It is also good practise to have a numberic field as PK as these are more likely to be unique and not change, unlike a having a text field as you PK.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, numerical types like `INT` or `LONG` fields are used for PK fields because they can be automatically generated by the DBMS and are more efficient in terms of storage space usage, than `CHAR`-type datatypes.

With character-type key fields, you do not have the advantage of using sequences to cleanly generate key-field values. The database cannot manage your key fields for you and you'll probably have to come up with some contrived scheme to maintain uniqueness. Not to mention the storage space that will be wasted.

Define a field with a `LONG` and use that as your PK field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have other than numeric fields as the primary key. Numeric values are simply more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it, but it is not convenient. Otherwise if it fits your needs, you can generate it in hibernate like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String ID;
```

By the way, usually id as "String" type is not correlation id, it isn't more than external id to your system...so it should be unique only in your system.